# Change default selected value of drop-down box

Tags: drop-down-menu, html-select, selecteditem, selected

I would like to modify a webpage used at my job to query information. This page is on our internal server (that is, it's not publically available), and uses a .aspx extension. The page has drop-down menu with a default value; I don't use the defaulted value in my job, so I would like to change the default value.

Here is the section of HTML code containing the drop-down box:

```
<select name="ComboCountry" id="ComboCountry">
  <option selected="selected" value="US">US</option>
  <option value="CN">Canada</option>
</select>
```

I would like to know how to automatically set the drop-down box value to "Canada". I have programmed in C and created very simple webpages, but I have never modified a page's content before. So, the Google searching began! I searched and found  one website, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp, which suggested "the selected attribute can also be set after the page loads, with a JavaScript." Searching some more on this site, as well as on Google, for help with javascript to change a webpage showed lots of hits to *set* a selected value when building your own page, but none to change someone else's webpage. As well, I did stumble onto Greasemonkey which has lots of possibilities, but our company computers do not permit installing software ourselves, so a different solution is necessary.

The browser I am using is IE version 8.

Thanks in advance! I believe I have listed all the required details, but if there is anything else required please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Move selected to Canada or use the name attribute. If you want a more dynamic implementation use JQuery. Also what does your code do. Explain more if you want a clearer answer.